# PHP SVN update - TortoiseSVN

Tags: php, windows, svn, command-line, tortoisesvn

New code:

```
<?php
exec('"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" update "c:\wamp\www\project"');
```

This results in an infinite loop, no result is returned. What am I doing wrong?

**== edit ==**

On Windows, I'm trying to update a project by using PHP. I'm having problems using the commandline: I want visual feedback (important in case of conflicts), so I don't want to start as a background process. Is this possible?

The code I have so far is:

```
<?php
$todo = "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\\"";
$todo2 = "START TortoiseProc.exe /command:update /path:\"C:\\wamp\\www\\project\\\" /closeonend:0";

 pclose(popen($todo, "r"));  
 pclose(popen($todo2, "r"));
```

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this first? http://php.net/manual/en/book.svn.php

Comment: There is no php_svn.dll precompiled for Windows. And I don't have the know-how.

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. `TortoiseProc.exe` is not meant to be used from other software in a non-GUI/non-interactive mode. @tlenss has pointed you in the right direction, or you can use [phpsvnclient](https://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/), or the real command-line client (`svn.exe`, comes with TortoiseSVN since 1.7).

Comment: @Kevin You can use pecl to install it

Comment: I've updates Tortoise, my new code i'll post - @alroc.

Comment: @Simon do you have a working code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would drop **exec** and use **proc_open** (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Here's an example I quickly whipped up and which should work for you:

```
<?php
// setup pipes that you'll use
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),    // stdin
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),    // stdout
    2 => array("pipe", "w")     // stderr
);

// call your process
$process = proc_open('"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" update "c:\wamp\www\project"',
                     $descriptorspec,
                     $pipes);

// if process is called, pipe data to variables which can later be processed.
if(is_resource($process)) 
{
    $stdin = stream_get_contents($pipes[0]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);  
    fclose($pipes[1]);  
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);   
}

// Now it's up to you what you want to do with the data you've got.
// Remember that this is merely an example, you'll probably want to 
// modify the output handling to your own likings...

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');  

// check if there was an error, if not - dump the data
if($return_value === -1)    
{
    echo('The termination status of the process indicates an error.'."\r\n");
}

echo('---------------------------------'."\r\n".'STDIN contains:'."\r\n");
echo($stdin);
echo('---------------------------------'."\r\n".'STDOUTcontains:'."\r\n");
echo($stdout);
echo('---------------------------------'."\r\n".'STDERR contains:'."\r\n");
echo($stderr);

?>
```

---

### Aside:

The line

```
// call your process
$process = proc_open('"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" update "c:\wamp\www\project"',
                     $descriptorspec,
                     $pipes);
```

could also be escaped like this

```
// call your process
$process = proc_open("\"C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\svn.exe\" update \"c:\\wamp\\www\\project\"",
                     $descriptorspec,
                     $pipes);
```

which might or might not solve some problems on some systems that have hickups with the single brackets (`'`) and spaces () in the notation.

Comment: Why is proc_open better? I've read that it has huge disadvantages

Comment: I used this code i get an error. 

"STDERR contains:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

can you please help me ?

Comment: @myco-claro Seems like it's having trouble with either the paths, or with finding an executable/runnable file at the location you provided. I can't diagnose this from a distance, but you should double-check if the paths indeed point to the correct dirs and that that the paths and file loxation indeed exist. If not, adapt appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. can you please check my files ? I will show you my screenshot.. 
Output: http://prntscr.com/li2alg
Code: http://prntscr.com/li2ayx
File Path: http://prntscr.com/li2b6o
SVN Path: http://prntscr.com/li2be7

Please help me bro. thanks :)

Comment: @MycoClaro Looks OK and should actually work. Obviously, the code itself is nevertheless failing for you… exactly at line 10 – where it does not seem to parse the `"` correctly and therefore thinks the space between `Program` and `Files` marks another parameter. Not at home atm so I can’t try to reproduce or test, but you could try replacing line 10 with `$process = proc_open("\"C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin\\svn.exe\" update \"c:\\xampp2\\www\\test_tills\"",`. It’s just another way to escape the string, but maybe it works for you. As said: can’t test, just doing this from my head here.

Comment: @MycoClaro In case of doubt, see the edit (the “**Aside**” at the end). Hope that helps.

Comment: @myco-claro Sorry to hear that. Back in the days when I posted the answer (2013) it worked flawlessly. The issue is that space in "Program Files" that somehow doesn't get pushed to the terminal as it's supposed to. But as I'm still on the road, I can't help more than I tried already. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: okay.. anyway thanks man.. But now I do some way to Open my SVN and It's work fine now.. It's just a command on the SVN .
Code: <a href="tsvncmd:command:update?path:C:\xampp\htdocs\file">