# php TortoiseSVN exec - export command

Tags: php, windows, svn, tortoisesvn, exec

How can I execute the update command of SVN via PHP? I'm using TortoiseSVN. In "cmd.exe" the following command works:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" export https://server:8443/project "c:\project"
```

When using the php "exec" function it suddenly doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP SVN update - TortoiseSVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388589/php-svn-update-tortoisesvn)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP config need to allow the shell functions (ie: not in the `disable_functions` directive).

Afterwards, try using the command: `var_dump(shell_exec($cmd))`

Comment: Shell functions are enabled, but the command you suggest just makes the script run forever.

Comment: How long does the command last by just running it in normal CMD prompt?

Comment: See possible duplicate comment from @alroc

Comment: I've seen and tested the comments on that page. did not work. any suggestions?

Comment: It's *probably* something with your SVN path. Try using the DOS 8.3 path (`dir /x`) for the svn.exe.

Comment: I've found that the error has to do with the Server. When the server is found, the script loops forever. When it doesn't, it ends like expected.